# rounding conerted values to i decimal place

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a code that converts a value in a jtextfield to 60%. The code divides the value in the textfield by 100 and multiplies it by 60. My problem is when the textfield has a value like 79, the result of that calculation becomes 47.4000000000006. 
how do I get it rounded so that I get a result like 47.4

below is my code:

```
int ex,exCal;
        ex = Integer.valueOf(classExam1.getText());
        exCal = (ex/100)*60;
System.out.PrintIn(exCal)
```

please all help will be well appreciated. thank you.

It was initially using double for that but because it was giving me the decimal places, I decided to use int but I still get the same result

Comment: `The result of that calculation becomes 47.4000000000006` - This is impossible, since both variables are of type `int`

Comment: `int / 100 * 60` return an `int`. You are using a `float`/`double`  somewhere, and off course, `exCal` is a `float`/`double` to give you decimal like this. Post a [mcve] please...

Answer (score 1):

You can use DecimalFormat class:

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".#");
double input = 47.4000000000006;
System.out.println("double : " + input);
System.out.println("double : " + df2.format(input));
```

**That code prints:**

`double : 47.4000000000006`

`double : 47.4`

Comment: DecimalFormat class is not recorgnized in my jdk 8 @Eleazar. tried it but

Comment: Are you sure?... What's the Java version you're using?  DecimalFormat was included in Java since version 1.4.

Comment: ok I see it. guess it was too slow to load. but even after applying it, I don't see it converting. I still get the same result. is there anything I need to include in the (".#")

Comment: sorry bro...it worked. thanks. guess am working under too much pressure that's why. thanks alot

Comment: Note that this will produce a local formatted `String`. On some settings, it will produce `47,4` instead of `47.4`

Comment: @EleazarEnrique guide me to where I need to vote your answer for you ok. am quite new to stack overflow and not too familiar with the structure of how things get done here. please how do I upvote and accept your answer

Comment: Hello, at the left of the answer there are two arrows, click on the arrow to increase the count of votes.  Further, click on the check just below of the arrows to accept the answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
 String df2 = new DecimalFormat("$##.#").format(input);
 System.out.println(df2);
```